# Comparing Date in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, r, datetime

My oracle sql data has a structure like this

```
CALENDAR_MONTH_END_DT  |PX_LAST|
-----------------------+-------+
1900-01-31 00:00:00.000|      1|
1900-02-28 00:00:00.000|      1|
```

CALENDAR_MONTH_END_DT  is a Date variable

I will be calling the sql code using Rscript data where I pass a variable minDate as `'YYYYMMDD'`

I want to filter my output based on the rows having CALENDAR_MONTH_END_DT>minDate. What is the best way to do that

Comment: I apologize that I cannot check oracle, but most (all?) SQL databases I work with will accept the unambiguous `YYYY-MM-DD`, which means you can do `WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH_END_DT > '2021-01-15'`. Have you tried just `YYYYMMDD`? If it doesn't work, I think it might be easy for R to convert that into a `Date`-object with `as.Date(x, format="%Y%m%d")`.

Comment: Oracle supports `to_date('20210115','YYYYMMDD')` or `date '2021-01-15'`